# Как узнать scroolbar div height?

Tags: javascript

Можно узнать scroolbar body height через такой код

```
var scrollBarHeight=(window.innerHeight-3)/document.body.offsetHeight*window.innerHeight;
```

А как узнать scroolbar div height?

```
var element = document.getElementById("content");
var scrollBarHeight=(window.innerHeight-3)/element.offsetHeight*window.innerHeight;
```

Чета не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно в расчёт надо принимать размеры div и/или элемента, в котором находится этот div, а не window?

Comment: @KYRAN Вам нужен размер самой области, которая сканируется, или размер контрола scollbar?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow размер контрола scollbar

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо за внимание от души

Comment: @KYRAN Не за что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или это?

```
var element = document.getElementById("content");
var scrollBarHeight = (element.clientHeight - 3) / element.scrollHeight * element.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Comment: Пожалуйста. И ещё замечу, что по-моему вместо -3 надо отнять  высоту обеих кнопок вверх и вниз scrollbar-а. Если, конечно, нужна такая точность.

Comment: Ну вы прав. Просто у меня пример